# Error in ROSWTF and doubt in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

Tags: ros, ros-package-path, roswtf, pythonpath

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My questions are at the end.

When i use the command to find the ROS PACKAGE PATH

```
sai@sai-desktop:~/fuerte_workspace$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/home/sai/fuerte_workspace/help:/home/sai/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot_driver:/home/sai/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot:/home/sai/fuerte_workspace/sandbox:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
```

After this, ROSWTF results in

```
sai@sai-desktop:~/fuerte_workspace$ roswtf

Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

Found 2 error(s).

ERROR Not all paths in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH [/home/sai/fuerte_workspace/help:/home/sai/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot_driver:/home/sai/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot:/home/sai/fuerte_workspace/sandbox:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros] point to an existing directory: 
 * /home/sai/fuerte_workspace/help

ERROR Not all paths in PYTHONPATH [/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages:/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages:] point to a directory: 
 * /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/roslib/src

================================================================================

ROS Master does not appear to be running.
Online graph checks will not be run.
ROS_MASTER_URI is [http://localhost:11311]


------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then I changed the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to

```
sai@sai-desktop:~/fuerte_workspace$ ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/sai/fuerte_workspace/sandbox:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:
```

Then ROSWTF results in

```
sai@sai-desktop:~/fuerte_workspace$ roswtf
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

Found 1 error(s).

ERROR Not all paths in PYTHONPATH [/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages:/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages:] point to a directory: 
 * /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/roslib/src

================================================================================

ROS Master does not appear to be running.
Online graph checks will not be run.
ROS_MASTER_URI is [http://localhost:11311]
```

My questions are

1. Initially why did the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH has such a big path?
2. Why are the errors turning up in ROSWTF?
3. The new ROS_PACKAGE_PATH which i have changed is a subset of old PATH. Is it OK to have a big path as the old one or do I have to change to new path?

Please let me know what i should do

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40577/error-in-roswtf-and-doubt-in-ros_package_path/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2012-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS_PACKAGE_PATH in your case includes all entries in
/home/sai/fuerte_workspace/.rosinstall
you can manage this file using rosws:  [www.ros.org/wiki/rosws](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosws)

The ROS_PACKAGE_PATH can be very long, no problem. But all the paths in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH should exist, else they can be deleted.

The shortened ROS_PACKAGE path you posted does not include

```
/home/sai/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot_driver:/home/sai/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot
```

but if you want to use those packages, they need to be in the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. Just remove

```
/home/sai/fuerte_workspace/help
```

from your /home/sai/fuerte_workspace/.rosinstall file

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ee05073](https://answers.ros.org/users/2918/ee05073/) on 2012-10-02**:
What about the Python Path error? is it the same?

**Comment by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) on 2022-04-27**:
@ee05073 did you had an error with pythonpath?